# hide UINavigationBar from @selector

Tags: c#, ios, xcode

I have a simple WebView application. In one of the cases, I show a file, to allow user go back a `UINavigationBar` is shown:

```
navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44)];
navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                target:self
                                                action:@selector(buttonClicked:)];;

[navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
```

This is working nice. It shows a back button, and when back button is clicked it executes selector (button style must be improved, but I'm newbie with `xCode` and `c#` and this will come later).

In the selector i load previous url, but I can't figure out how to hide button and bar.

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    return [self.webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: lastURL]]];
}
```

I've tried several things, like `removeFromSuperView`:

```
[navigationBar removeFromSuperview];
```

Hide it:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

// or

[navigationItem hidesBackButton];

// or

navigationBar.hidden = TRUE;
```

Using the selector `(id)`:

```
[sender show:NO];
```

Using the `alpha` property:

```
navigationBar.alpha = 0,0;
```

Free memory space:

```
navigationItem.dealloc;
```

But nothing works... I think I'm missing some important detail, because I don't know really how `xCode` works...

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would never add a navigation bar like that, but rather have a root navigation controller, which has a root view controller that holds a webview as it's view.

You did not make it very clear, how do you actually show the file?

Anyway, this code:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

is not working for you because you haven't provided your view controller with a navigation controller.

Provide one, maybe best in the main storyboard, and setup your view controller (that holds the webview) as its root view controller. To do that, open the storyboard, and drag/drop a UINavigationController to the main area. You have to tick the option "Is Initial View Controller". **Note**: when you did the drag/drop, a default root view controller was already provided. You can either leave that one, or provide your own, if you already had one in the storyboard. To do that, delete the linked one, and ctrl-click and drag from the Navigation Controller to the View Controller, to setup it as its Root View Controller. I've attached an image to showcase what I've described.

[image: Main storyboard setup]

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I'm totally new in that. I will check how to add root navigation controller. I didn't explain how I show the file because `webView` handles it perfectly, problem is resulting preview doesn't allow user go back...

Comment: Added some more info on how to setup the storyboard. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: I did figured out how to make it works with your previous clues, but now is a great answer... accepting in 3...2..1... ;)